# Regular Expression to get a string between code contianing a dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which returns a string which is between `` and containing a dot. For example: I want to get the string which resides between the strings "`"

and "`" and containing a dot(.)

```
My names is `James.Bond`.
```

would return

```
James.Bond
```

My names is `James Bond`.

is false cause it's not containing a dot(.)

But I'm new with regex.

what i was able to perform this

```
/`([^.)]+`)/
```

This will return

```
            `James Bond`
```

Comment: One dot or 1 or more?

Comment: Containing only one dot

Comment: I suspect you also do not want to match whitespaces in between the backticks, right?  Then, you'll need ``/`([^\s`.]*\.[^\s`.]*)`/g``

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
/`([^`.]*\.[^`.]*)`/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SS6u1D/2).

**Details**

- `` ` `` - a backtick
- `` ([^`.]*\.[^`.]*) `` - Group 1: 0+ chars other than a backtick and a dot, a dot, and again 0+ chars other than a backtick and a dot
- `` ` `` - a backtick.

JS demo:

```js
var text = "My name is `James.Bond`. His name is `Jack.Smith`. Her name is `Whats.Her.Name`";
var rx = /`([^`.]*\.[^`.]*)`/g;
var results=[], m;
while(m=rx.exec(text)) {
  results.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(results);
```

A code snippet with `.matchAll`:

```js
let text = "My name is `James.Bond`. His name is `Jack.Smith`. Her name is `Whats.Her.Name`";
let matchData = [...text.matchAll(/`([^`.]*\.[^`.]*)`/g)];
console.log(Array.from(matchData, m => m[1]));
```

Comment: This will work with an exemple like that My names is `James...Bond`.

I would like it to work with only one and only one dot, and return me what is inside the backtick

Comment: @StillLearningHowtodoit It [won't match](https://regex101.com/r/SS6u1D/3) `James...Bond`

Comment: In the second snippet you can do `Array.from(matchData` directly on `matchData`.

Comment: @trincot Yes, unless the user wants to get whole matches, or re-use `matchData` in any other way. `matchData` is not re-iterable. ``let matchData = [...text.matchAll(/`([^`.]*\.[^`.]*)`/g)]`` will do to make it shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
let reg = /`[A-Za-z]*[.][A-Za-z]*`/g;

console.log("`James.Bond`".match(reg));
console.log("`James..Bond`".match(reg));
console.log("`James.Bondsdfsdf`".match(reg));
console.log("`.James.Bond`".match(reg));
console.log("`James.Bond.James`".match(reg));
```

Answer (score 0):

This regexp works:

```
/`\w+\.\w+`/
```

```js
const re = /`\w+\.\w+`/
const arr = [
  "`James.Bond`",
  "`James Bond`",
  "James.Bond",
  "`Miss.Moneypenny`"
]

const match = arr.map(str => str.match(re) === null ? false : true)
console.log(match)
```